# Creating a WP shop with woocommerce and automatic detection of existing relative products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello my current project is as it says in the name creation a WP shop with woocommerce and automatic detection of existing relative products. What that means is that my products will be Bathrooms and the items used to furnish the bathrooms. What i envision for the layout is a photo of the bathroom basic content price and buy button after which there will be tabs for tiles and furniture that was used in the construction of the bathroom, the tabs will include list of the used tiles with basic info for each. What i find difficult is how to fill the tabs with content. What i came up till now is to create a category for each product specific tab ex. if my bathroom is called cuha i will create a category named cuha-tiles, cuha-furniture, and fill it with the specific products afterwhich on each bathroom page there will be a check wheter a category with the name of the bathroom exist. To call the tabs however i intend to emplement the folowing code in `single-product.php (woocommerce/single-product.php)`

```
<?php
$term = term_exists('wp_title()' . '-' . 'tiles' , 'product_cat');
if ($term !== 0 && $term !== null) {
    echo Category list;
}
?>
```

However i can't get the code to work i would. sorry for the long explanation and my bad english i hope that atleast someone managed to understand me and will be able to help if you guys need more clarification feel free to ask